# Getting a URL in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose my current [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is `http://www.example.com/person/peter.html`. How can I use PHP to get "http://www.example.com/person/" (just exclude "peter.html")?

Comment: Don't you mean get http://www.example.com/person/peter ?

Comment: @yoda Because how can the current page have an html extension, but still use PHP, right? Maybe there's some modrewriting going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't include the protocol, but is a first attempt.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].
    pathinfo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
```

Determining what the protocol is can be tricky. Methods include:

- Checking $_SERVER['HTTPS'], which can vary depending on the webserver, and if Named Virtual Hosts are being used (not verified). Apache will not set the value if it is not https, however IIS sets it to 'off'
- Checking the $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'], again http doesn't have to be on port 80, and https doesn't have to be on port 443.

Comment: Why the `pathinfo`? Isn't `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` sufficient?

Comment: REQUEST_URI includes the filename, which the asker is trying to remove.

Comment: Aach, so it does. I had a quick test set up, but didn't catch that. Apparently it was *too* quick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `$_SERVER` superglobal and a bit of work

```
$protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$pathInfo = pathinfo( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); //returns an associative array
$dirname  = $pathInfo['dirname'];

$baseUrl = $protocol . $host . $dirname;
```

[Docs on $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)
[Docs on pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)